# MSP430FR4133 - How do i read in an external input signal

Tags: capture, msp430, adc

I am trying to read in an input voltage signal from a heart rate detector using an infrared sensor and a signal conditioning circuit. I want to be able to capture and display the signal in terms of `beats / minute`. I'm not worried about the LCD: I just want to actually connect and obtain this value.

Do I use ADC? Do I use `Timer A`? How do I go about doing this?

The below is where I am at right now, and am uncertain how to proceed:

```
(input pin 1.7)
(Timer A Code)


    TA0CCTL |= CM_1; //Rising edge
    TA0CCTL |= CCIS_0; //Use CCI0A (P1.7)
    TA0CCL |= SCS; //Synchronise capture
    TA0CCL |= CAP; //Capture Mode

    P1SEL |= GPIO_PIN7; //Connect to timer
    P1DIR != GPIO_PIN7; //Set as input
```

Comment: What is your incoming signal? TTL? An analog voltage?

Comment: @HeadCode An analogue signal (heart rate pulse)